# Consulta Mysql - Duas tabelas e intervalo de datas

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma para o cadastro de técnicos e uma para as tarefas.
É uma relação 1-->N.

Tabela 1 (TECNICO):

```
cd_tecnico | nome
```

Tabela 2 (TAREFA)

```
cd_tarefa | cd_tecnico | dt_inicio | dt_fim
```

Preciso de dois filtros para verificar em uma data qualquer (informada pelo usuário) quem está e quem não está em uma tarefa.

1 - Listar quem está em uma tarefa na data informada. Aqui está funcionando OK.

```
Select * from TECNICO tec
inner join TAREFA ta ON 
ta.cd_tecnico = tec.cd_tecnico
and 
(ta.dt_inicio <='2016-03-10' and ta.dt_conclusao>='2016-03-10')
```

2 - Listar quem está não está em uma tarefa na data informada.

Aqui está a minha dúvida na melhor forma de fazer. Tentei um select de outro select mas ficou muito lento e não funcionou direto.

Qual seria a melhor solução neste caso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `left join` para trazer todos os *TECNICO*, e um `Case` para verificar quem tem ou não tarefa.

```
declare @TECNICO table
(
  cd_tecnico int,
  nome varchar (30)
)

declare @TAREFA table
(
  cd_tecnico int,
  cd_tarefa int,
  nome varchar (30),
  dt_inicio date,
  dt_conclusao date
)


insert into @TECNICO values
(1, 'João'),
(2, 'Pedro'),
(3, 'Maria'),
(4, 'Carlos'),
(5, 'Antonio')


insert into @TAREFA values
(1, 1 ,'Correção banco', '2016-03-10', '2016-03-10' ),
(2, 1 ,'Correção app', '2016-03-10', '2016-03-10' ),
(3, 1 ,'Correção grid', '2016-03-11', '2016-03-11' ),
(5, 1 ,'Correção banco', '2016-03-10', '2016-03-10' )

Select *, case when ta.cd_tecnico is not null then 'Tem tarefa'  else 'não tem tarefa' end as Tarefa
from @TECNICO tec
left join @TAREFA ta 
ON ta.cd_tecnico = tec.cd_tecnico
and (ta.dt_inicio <='2016-03-10' and ta.dt_conclusao >= '2016-03-10')
```

Comment: ótima solução (case when) e performático!! :-D Parabéns!

Comment: Valeu Dot Net. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Uma resposta completa para você refletir (não coloquei as condições da clausula where, fica a seu critério).

Um jeito tradicional é usar sub-consultas para o que você precisa isto funcionará na maioria dos SGBDs e não somente no MySQL. Claro, esta é uma solução caso o SGBD não possua recurso disponível de Case When, utilizado na outra resposta pelo amigo @DotNet.

Vale lembrar que é importante medir o desempenho da consulta, pois quando se utiliza subconsultas, o consumo pode ser elevado.

```
CREATE TABLE TECNICO(
    CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    NOME VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TAREFA(
    CODIGO INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRICAO VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    DATA_INICIO DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    DATA_FIM DATETIME NOT NULL,
    TECNICO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_TAREFA_TECNICO FOREIGN KEY (TECNICO)
    REFERENCES TECNICO(CODIGO)
);

INSERT INTO TECNICO VALUES (1,'MATEUS');
INSERT INTO TECNICO VALUES (2,'JOSÉ');
INSERT INTO TECNICO VALUES (3,'CARLOS');
INSERT INTO TECNICO VALUES (4,'PATRÍCIA');

INSERT INTO TAREFA VALUES (100, 'CRIAR EJBs',
STR_TO_DATE('1/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),
STR_TO_DATE('30/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),1);

INSERT INTO TAREFA VALUES (101, 'Criar testes unitarios',
STR_TO_DATE('15/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),
STR_TO_DATE('30/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),1);

INSERT INTO TAREFA VALUES (102, 'Gerar build',
STR_TO_DATE('1/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),
STR_TO_DATE('2/6/2016 8:06:26 AM', '%d/%m/%Y %r'),2);

-- Aqui temos uma junção interna (só trará as correspondências que existem)
SELECT * FROM TECNICO te
inner join TAREFA ta ON te.CODIGO = ta.TECNICO;

-- Trará quem tem ou não tarefa (juntos - à esquerda)
SELECT * FROM TECNICO te
left outer join TAREFA ta ON te.CODIGO = ta.TECNICO;

-- Só os técnicos que não possuem tarefa. A query interna retorna os tecnicos que possuem tarefas e a externas aqueles que estão fora do conjunto. bastaria você acescentar a clausula where no select interno (subconsulta).
SELECT * FROM TECNICO te where te.codigo NOT IN (SELECT te.codigo FROM TECNICO te
inner join TAREFA ta ON te.CODIGO = ta.TECNICO)
```

Comment: NOT IN, tem um custo alto nesse caso.

Comment: @DotNet exato! Por isso mesmo que na resposta acrescentei que pode ser um banco legado que não tenha recurso de Case When. Já tive problemas com um DB2 antigo que não oferecia esse recurso.

Comment: Se tive suporte nesse caso o exists seria melhor

Comment: Sim! No Oracle por exemplo, 11g é recomendável o NOT EXISTS, no DB2, tanto faz ;-)

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda Mateus.